# ZSH auto completion provide full path to files in a specific folder

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I'm trying to write an autocomplete function for a custom executable that takes file arguments from a particular folder.

`$ ./my_executable <tab>`
should provide the files in folder `/home/me/argument_files`.

I got that to work with:
`compdef '_files -W /home/me/argument_files' my_executable`

The problem is that I need to provide the full path to the argument files to `my_executable`. This only provides `$ /home/me/my_executable file1` as opposed to

`$ /home/me/my_executable /home/me/argument_files/file1`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `compadd` -P option:

```
compdef '_files -P /home/me/argument_files -W /home/me/argument_files' my_executable
```